# Hello World program in PySpark - EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

I am novice in AWS. I am trying to execute a hello world code in EMR. My code is in S3 bucket.
My first code is an one liner:

`print ('Hello World')`

I submitted my code thru add step:

[image]

My log says :

```
Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
```

My second code is :

```
import val


from pyspark.python.pyspark.shell import spark

val jdbcDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xxxx").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "pet").option("user", "root").option("password", "xxxx").load()
print("done")

jdbcDF.write.format("json").mode("append").save("${s3://demo-xxxx}")
```

I am getting the same Access denied error.

Please guide me. Not sure if the cluster itself does not have S3 access. If so, how can I provide access. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A [step](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-add-steps-console.html) in EMR is a MR/Spark/Hive/Pig etc programs and your program is none of it. Try to get comfortable with Big Data first and then look at Big Data on AWS.

Comment: I have executed one more code too. Edited the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely S3 access issue.

Each node (EC2) have one IAM role to access AWS resources.
And that EMR EC2 IAM role should have putObject access to your `demo-xxxx` S3 bucket

See [this AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-iam-roles.html)